# Errors in "getRetweetCount()" method

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

While trying to retrieve data from twitter using Netbeans,  I got an error in "getRetweetCount()" ... It seems like it doesn't exist or something!! I'm using the Twitter4j-core-2.1.1.jar
Any help please?!

Comment: Can you post the complete error, you should be using latest version of Twitter4j

Comment: May be you forgot to import the JARs!